# Call web api in web form by referencing API dll

Tags: asp.net-web-api

is it Ok if we call wep api service inside web form using api dll. we will be hosting both api and application on same server and requiring internal calling.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit?  Are you talking about calling the endpoint through HTTP or are you talking about instantiating one of the objects in the dll and calling one or more methods?

Comment: We dont want to have a seperate http request from web form to web api

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are after.

First of all if you write an API of some kind then you have to call it to interact with it. There's no middle ground here. If you don't want to call anything then you don't need an API. The purpose of an API is to provide a way to interact with some data storage, so behind your controllers you'd have a layer which talks to a database for example, or even another API.

If you don't want to make any calls then why bother with an API at all? Write a class library, one or several, doing whatever you need them to do and interact with your database this way.

I worked in a project before where I had a somewhat similar situation and ended up writing class libraries which were then shared by a UI project and a WebApi project, so you could work with them either way. This worked quite well actually. If you are looking for something similar then that's what I would go with. Keep the stuff of interest separate so you can expose with an API call or a direct dll reference.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that your controller methods look something like this:

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<Value> GetValueAsync(int id);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public Task<Value> GetValueAsync(int id)
    {
    //...
    // Code to return a value
    //...
    }
}

public class ValueController : ApiController
{
    private IService _service;

    public ValueController(IService service)
    {
         _service = service
    }

    public Task<IHttpActionResult> GetValueAsync(int id)
    {
        return Ok(await _service.GetValueAsync(id));
    }
}
```

Then it is perfectly okay to call the method in the Service class.  I would not call the method in the controller as that will cause more problems than you probably want to deal with.